# Redirect joomla url's to my new wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, joomla

My previous site, which was with Joomla, has about 7,000 urls in it. When it was transferred to the new WordPress site, all these 7,000 links should be redirected according to the following template.

```
old jomla url :
     .com/downloads/learning-video/1934-sample.html
new wordpress url :
     .com/sample
```

Is there a solution to do all the redirects automatically?

Comment: How was it transferred, and most importantly why was this not handled as part of the migration?

Comment: I used the "FG Joomla to WordPress" plugin to migrate.
  Because the number of links on my previous site in Google is about 7,000, these redirects must be done.

Comment: You might want to bring this up with the developer. Else you could do it manually with an .htaccess rewrite rule, with a regular expression you should be able to handle it.